# React native iOS how to make background process after getting new remote notification, without opening the app

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I use react-native-firebase to get remote notification, and i want after getting remote notification(data-only) **to do some process in background, without opening the app** (without tapping on the notification).

- I achieved that in android with Headless JS.
- **I really want to find how to do that in iOS**

I read about:

1. Notification Service Extension - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension
2. https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification

But I didn't get it to work, maybe someone has experience with this situation?

Comment: This may help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: @aytek Thank you for response, I saw that but i don't know how to implement it with react native(i use this in react-native-firbase but when i get data only notification and the app is closed i didn't get the data only after i open the app), and they wrote in the Important "The number of background notifications allowed by the system depends on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than two or three per hour." And i want to use it to get messages and other notification- so three per hour it's not an option.